# why am i getting Null Pointer Exception?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, cursor, nullpointerexception

I am fetching data from a database using this code :

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(News_Table, null, null, null, null, null, null);

if (cursor != null) 
{
    cursor.moveToFirst();
}
allNews = new News[cursor.getCount()];
int i = 0;

while (!(cursor.isLast())) 
{
    allNews[i] = new News(cursor.getInt(0), cursor.getString(2),
            cursor.getString(1));
    cursor.moveToNext();
    i++;
}
```

This is how my table looks :
[image]

But everytime my last row is not being fetched and i get a null pointer exception. Here is the log cat screen :
[image]

Why is my code running only for n-1 rows correctly and giving a problem on the (n)th row, where n is the total number of rows in my news table.

Comment: You check `cursor != null` and then three lines later use it as if it couldn't be null with `cursor.getCount()`  either the null check isn't required, or your code cannot handle null values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

cursor.isLast() will return true when the cursor is on the last row, and so your while loop will stop at that point having not read & processed the last row. typically the pattern for iterating a cursor would be (note this doesn't call `moveToFirst()` either)

```
Cursor cursor = getACursor();
int i = 0;
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
   /// do something with this row
   allNews[i] = new News(cursor.getInt(0), cursor.getString(2),cursor.getString(1));
   i++;
}
```

Comment: I agree. The NPE is thrown later, probably when the author tries to loop through `allNews` but the last item is still null.

Comment: Yes this code works, but i still didn't understand the flaw in my code, because the same code that i use works somewhere else perfectly in my app. then why not here?

Comment: if you have the same while(!last) construct, then its wrong elsewhere as well, perhaps that case doesn't hit the later NPE and so you haven't noticed.

Answer (score 1):

```
while (!(cursor.isLast()))
```

I think issue while not of `isLast()`. You are explicitly saying if not last row.

Change while loop to:

```
 while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
   //Your code.
}
```